# using tr to strip characters but keep line breaks

Tags: linux, tr

I am trying to format some text that was converted from UTF-16 to ASCII, the output looks like this:

```
C^@H^@M^@M^@2^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
T^@h^@e^@m^@e^@ ^@M^@a^@n^@a^@g^@e^@r^@ ^@f^@o^@r^@ ^@3^@D^@S^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

The only text I want out of that is:

```
CHMM2
Theme Manager for 3DS
```

So there is a line break "\n" at the end of each line and when I use

```
tr -cs 'a-zA-Z0-9' 'newtext' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

It is stripping the new line as well so all the text ends up in one big string on one line.

Can anyone assist with figuring out how to strip out only the ^@'s and keeping spaces and new lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^@`s are most certainly null characters, \0s, so:

```
tr -d '\0'
```

Will get rid of them.

But this is not really the correct solution. You should simply use the`iconv` command to convert from `UTF-16` to `UTF-8` (see its man page for more information). That is, of course, what you're really trying to accomplish here, and this will be the correct way to do it.

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your problem is not deleting the null characters. Your real problem is how to convert from UTF-16 to either UTF-8, or maybe US-ASCII (and I chose UTF-8, as the conservative answer).

Comment: Ahhhhhh thank you so much, that did the trick.

This is just 1 step in a overly convoluted way of trying to scrape information from a binary file and output to a text file, so my solution is not very good, but it works and now with this I can progress further.